# How to get informed, if a listview remove a view (managed by adapter)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-mediaplayer

My `ListView` has an underlaying `ArrayAdapter`, which generates custom views. That's fine so far.

On some `Views` I have a `MediaPlayer` with automatic play. It plays very well, but I want to stop and unload the `View`, if the `Adapter` want to unload it.

Which event is fired, where I can stop and release my `MediaPlayer` in the view? Is the starting point my `Fragment`, `Adapter` or custom `View` in the `ListView`?

PS: At first, I looked at

```
public void remove(Object object) {
   ...
}
```

but this isn't the correct point, because I don't remove the underlaying data.

Comment: `I want to stop and unload the View, if the Adapter want to unload it.` Do you mean: "I want to stop the mediaplayer when the adapter wants to remove the view so the adapter can safely remove the view"? What do you mean exactly with 'unload'?

Comment: A ListView is a virtualized View component that is dependent on its backed data. It's a very bad idea to bind anything to a View inside the ListView outside the scope of the View itself. Please clarify what you mean by "unload the View" because ListView recycles all Views.

Comment: If you want to know in detail how a ListView works, it's strongly recommended to watch the Google I/O speech from 2010 https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=S226U_eSNtLZ4QTivICoCA&url=http://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70%26feature%3Dkp&cd=1&ved=0CB8QyCkwAA&usg=AFQjCNHcWSpiZcaY48dwaH8VK-ROpNh-hg&sig2=KEafElGofNNATkAjul4wAg

Comment: @greenapps Yes, exactly this.

Comment: You could let the adaptor stop the media player before it removed the view. But as you did not tell why/when the adaptor would remove a view we can not really advise. Why would an adapter want to remove a view? There should be some user interaction to start all.

Comment: @greenapps The view scrolls outside of the screen (top/bottom) and than the adapter removed the view (I think). I now stop my music with the help of the `convertedView` in `getView()`. It works, but I think it's not the best solution.

Comment: Adapters usually do not remove views when views scroll out of 'view'. Try to find out why views suddenly disappear. Do they disappear also when they do not contain a media player instance? Is the media player killed now beyond your control when the view scrolls out?

Comment: Is it your intention to stop a media player when it scrolls out of sight? Why?

Comment: `I want to stop and unload the View, if the Adapter wants to unload it.` We finally know what you ment: I want to stop the media player playing when the media player's view is recycled in my adapters getView method. Finally... And that is exactly the event you asked for.

Comment: @greenapps Okay, I thought there is another way but then, I let it with this `convertedView`. Thanks for your help.